# Simple API for Django using Tasty Pie

Tags: python, django, tastypie

New to Django, trying to create a simple API to build JSON for a map but stuck on foreign keys.

I've made a terrible attempt to figure it out but so far just an error is showing up:

```
 "error_message": "'unicode' object has no attribute 'all'"
```

Models.py:

```
from django.db import models

class HouseInformation(models.Model):
    house_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    house_type = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    latitude = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    longitude = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    class Meta:
        ordering  = ['house_name']

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.house_name + ', ' + self.house_type + ', ' + self.address

class InspectionReport(models.Model):
    house_name = models.ForeignKey(HouseInformation, to_field='house_name')
    pass_inspection = models.NullBooleanField()
    inspection_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    inspection_violations = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    file_name = models.CharField(max_length=40, default='none')
```

api.py:

```
from tastypie.resources import ModelResource
from tastypie import fields
from housing.models import HouseInformation, InspectionReport


class HouseAPI(ModelResource):
    # fields.ToManyField('APP.api.RelatedResource', 'related name')
    inspection_reports = fields.ToManyField('housing.api.InspectionAPI', 'house_name')

    class Meta:
        resource_name = 'house_inspections'
        queryset = HouseInformation.objects.all()

class InspectionAPI(ModelResource):
    house_information = fields.ToOneField(HouseAPI, 'house_name')

    class Meta:
        queryset = InspectionReport.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'inspection_reports'
```

urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import *
from housing.api import HouseAPI
from housing import views

housing_api = HouseAPI()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
        url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
        (r'^api/', include(housing_api.urls)),
)
```

UPDATES:

Testing URL: `http://localhost:8080/housing/api/house_inspections/?format=json`

Full Traceback given:

> {    "error_message":"'unicode' object has no attribute 'all'",
>   "traceback":"Traceback (most recent call last):\n\n  File
>   \"/Users/twitch/Projects/project_python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tastypie/resources.py\",
>   line 201, in wrapper\n    response = callback(request, *args,
>   **kwargs)\n\n  File \"/Users/twitch/Projects/project_python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tastypie/resources.py\",
>   line 432, in dispatch_list\n    return self.dispatch('list', request,
>   **kwargs)\n\n  File \"/Users/twitch/Projects/project_python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tastypie/resources.py\",
>   line 464, in dispatch\n    response = method(request, **kwargs)\n\n 
>   File
>   \"/Users/twitch/Projects/project_python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tastypie/resources.py\",
>   line 1299, in get_list\n    bundles.append(self.full_dehydrate(bundle,
>   for_list=True))\n\n  File
>   \"/Users/twitch/Projects/project_python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tastypie/resources.py\",
>   line 854, in full_dehydrate\n    bundle.data[field_name] =
>   field_object.dehydrate(bundle, for_list=for_list)\n\n  File
>   \"/Users/twitch/Projects/project_python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tastypie/fields.py\",
>   line 819, in dehydrate\n    for m2m in
>   the_m2ms.all():\n\nAttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute
>   'all'\n" }

Comment: when this was caused . place the url ..u used, or this occured when u run server?

Comment: what's the url you're hitting? What's the full trace back before the error message gets returned. Whats in `InspectionAPI`?

Comment: Added answers to the questions - thanks for helping! :)